# Visual Studio 2017 - Create an offline installation through network share and Ansible Playbook

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, ansible, offline, network-share

I'm attempting to create an offline Visual Studio 2017 installation with network share and Ansible.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly is going on since the installation loops(?) without much logging, the logs are often vague and more than often tells me that the bootstrapper is downloading files from Microsoft.

I'm wondering if there are easier ways to do this with Ansible.

I've used the following guides from Microsoft to try to make sense of things:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/automated-installation-with-response-file?view=vs-2017

Possibly problematic issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1531

The setup:

I've created a network share that is available as so:
\\Share\VisualStudio2017\

The share has (currently) no restriction while testing, so that means "everyone" can read its content.

The share is populated by the following layout command

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout \\<server>\Share\Development\VisualStudio2017 --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools --includeRecommended
```

Updated the Response.json (in the share) to

```
{
    "installChannelUri": "\\<server>\\Share\\Development\\VisualStudio2017\\ChannelManifest.json",
    "channelUri": "\\<server>\\Share\\Development\\VisualStudio2017\\ChannelManifest.json",
    "installCatalogUri": "\\<server>\\Share\\Development\\VisualStudio2017\\Catalog.json",
    "channelId": "VisualStudio.15.Release",
    "productId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise",
    "add": [
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop;includeRecommended",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop;includeRecommended",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools;includeRecommended",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat;includeRecommended",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb;includeRecommended",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node;includeRecommended",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal;includeRecommended"
    ],
    "addProductLang": [
        "en-US"
    ]
}
```

The share is combined with the role:

```
- name: Install Visual Studio 2017 
  win_package: 
     path: '\\<server>\share\Development\VisualStudio2017\vs_enterprise.exe'
     state: present
     product_id: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise
     channel_id: VisualStudio.15.Release
     user_name: <DOMAIN>\<USERNAME> 
     user_password: <PASSWORD>
     arguments: 
#        - --quiet
        - --wait
        - --norestart
#        - --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop 
#        - --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop 
#        - --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal 
#        - --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node 
#        - --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat 
#        - --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools 
#        - --includeRecommended
```

I'm running the playbook with the command with the verbose setting

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts utvClients.yaml -vvvv
```

Output

```
TASK [VisualStudio2017 : Install Visual Studio 2017] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /mnt/d/dev/Ansible/roles/VisualStudio2017/tasks/main.yaml:2
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_package.ps1
<192.168.56.101> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Ansible on PORT 5986 TO 192.168.56.101
checking if winrm_host 192.168.56.101 is an IPv6 address
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
```

The bootstrapper log on the host in the path C:\users\\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_bootstrapper_.log says this:

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 3/6/2019 9:43:56 AM
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: Commandline arguments = --wait,--norestart,--path cache="\\<server>\share\Development\VisualStudio2017\",--env,_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\Ansible\tyzrpvdy.v4j _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\Ansible
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: Parent process name = tyzrpvdy
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: Parent process product version = 15.9.28307.423
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: CampaignId = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: ResponseId not available in 'vs_setup_bootstrapper.config'. Trying to parse filename.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: loading config settings: -update --update --layout -offline --offline --locale --layout --originalworkingdir --installLayoutPath --env
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: DownloadURL = https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: InstallLocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: OfflineFilePath = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: LayoutLocation = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: ExecutableArguments = /finalizeInstall install --in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_201903060943571796.json" --norestart "--path cache="\\<server>\share\Development\VisualStudio2017\"" --locale en-US --activityId "d3c1a7c6-22ba-42af-9ce9-7ede1608e7be"
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: OSVersion = Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: Starting to detect the existing VS and .Net...
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/6/2019 9:43:57 AM: Finished detecting the existing VS and .Net
```

First off: DownloadUrl is still set to aka.ms? 
Am I not overriding it properly? Are there more things to consider?

Comment: Hi Verzada, it is recommended to use the https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel and please have a try with it, check it works or not.

Comment: Hi Sara Liu. 
I'm not sure what you mean by using the url, can you please elaborate.

I'm also made aware of the thread on GitHub https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1531
where lots of people are having problems installing Visual Studio 2017 through a network share

Comment: Hi, I found you update the Response.json with "channelUri": "\\<server>\\Share\\Development\\VisualStudio2017\\ChannelManifest.json", it seems the default value is the aka link that I mentioned. BTW, since I am not familiar with ansible playbook, so may be I misunderstand your issue, sorry for this inconvenience. Exclude the ansible part, do you still meet any issues if install VS 2017 using the network share?

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT
Yeah, I'm having the same issue. But I'll test some more to see if there's anything I've forgotten to do. However, the goal is to create an offline installation with a network share, therefore I don't see why the installation should even use the aka.ms url.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this to work.  I was able to get VS2019 to work, had to include the --noweb when I built the offline installer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Never got it to work for Visual Studio 2017